# Powershell Replace Error: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Creating a script to copy address info from one user to another.

getting the error:

```
Set-ADUser : replace
At line:33 char:5
+     Set-ADUser -Identity $touser -State $state -StreetAddress $address -Co ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (norrisl:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

even though there is no -replace property anywhere in the script.

FYI - I've replaced any private info with "text". The 'production' script has proper OU, server name, company name and phone numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
[string]$targetuser = read-host "`n Who's AD record are you editing? (Full name please)"
[string]$addressfromuser = read-host "`n Who would you like to copy OFFICE ADDRESS from? (Full name please)"


if($addressfromuser)
{
write-host "Please wait.." -foregroundcolor "green"
[string]$fromuser = get-aduser -Filter * -Properties * | where name -eq "$addressfromuser" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname
[string]$touser = get-aduser -Filter * -Properties * | where name -eq "$targetuser" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname 
[string]$address = Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties streetaddress | Select-Object -ExpandProperty streetaddress
[string]$state = Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties state | Select-Object -ExpandProperty state
[string]$country = Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties country | Select-Object -ExpandProperty country
[string]$city = Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties city | Select-Object -ExpandProperty city
[string]$postcode = Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties postalcode | Select-Object -ExpandProperty postalcode
[string]$pobox = Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties pobox | Select-Object -ExpandProperty pobox
[string]$fax = Get-ADUser $fromuser -Properties fax | Select-Object -ExpandProperty fax
[string]$company = "text"
if($state -eq "ACT"){[string]$phone = "text"}
if($state -eq "ACT"){[string]$ou = "text"}
if($state -eq "NSW"){[string]$phone = "text"}
if($state -eq "NSW"){[string]$ou = "text"}
if($state -eq "VIC"){[string]$phone = "text"}
if($state -eq "VIC"){[string]$ou = "text"}
if($state -eq "QLD"){[string]$phone = "text"}
if($state -eq "QLD"){[string]$ou = "text"}
if($state -eq "TAS"){[string]$phone = "text"}
if($state -eq "TAS"){[string]$ou = "text"}
if($state -eq "SA"){[string]$phone = "text"}
if($state -eq "SA"){[string]$ou = "text"}
if($state -eq "WA"){[string]$phone = "text"}
if($state -eq "WA"){[string]$ou = "text"}


Set-ADUser -Identity $touser -State $state -StreetAddress $address -Country $country -City $city -PostalCode $postcode -POBox $pobox -Fax $fax -Company $company -OfficePhone $phone
    Get-ADUser $touser | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $ou -Server "text"
Get-ADUser $touser -Properties streetaddress,state,country,city,postalcode,pobox,fax,OfficePhone | ft -AutoSize -Property name,streetaddress,state,country,city,postalcode,pobox,fax,OfficePhone

}
else {write-host "WARNING: NO NAME GIVEN `n" -foregroundcolor "red"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I finally figured out.
Was getting that damn error and tried everything.  What I needed to do was use `{&{` in order to have the other fields update with the Identity set in the first string.  What seemed to be happening is that it was loosing the Identity after the first command of `Office $_.Office`

Here is my script to import user csv and update the fields I want.  Everything after the `$_.` are my Headers in my CSV:

```
Import-Csv Test-Import.csv | % {&{ Set-ADUser -Identity
$_.sAMAccountName -Office $_.Office} {-Title $_.Title} {-Description
$_.Description} {-Department $_.Department} {-OfficePhone
$_.OfficePhone} {-Fax $_.Fax} {-MobilePhone $_.MobilePhone} {-Company
$_.Company} {-StreetAddress  $_.StreetAddress} {-City $_.City}
{-PostalCode $_.PostalCode} {-State $_.State} {-Country $_.Country}
{-HomePage $_.HomePage} }
```

Answer (score 0):

`-Replace` is only used for updating attributes which already don't have a parameter as part of `Set-Aduser`. You, of course, are using just the standard ones. After looking it up I didnt really see a concise reason for that error showing up. So the only thing I wonder about is if any of those attributes are being updating with incorrect values?

Either way I see some issues with your script that I would like to address for you. Repeated calls to `Get-AdUser` are redundant and add extra processing time that could be avoided. Also you are crying for a switch statement for all those `If`'s. A small clean up would be this:

```
[string]$targetuser = read-host "`n Who's AD record are you editing? (Full name please)"
[string]$addressfromuser = read-host "`n Who would you like to copy OFFICE ADDRESS from? (Full name please)"

if($addressfromuser)
{
write-host "Please wait.." -foregroundcolor "green"

$sourceUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq $addressfromuser} -Properties *
$targetUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq $targetuser}
$properties = @("StreetAddress","Country","PostalCode","POBox","Fax","OfficePhone","State")
$props = @{}

$properties | ForEach-Object{
    $props.$_ = $sourceUser.$_
}

$props.Company = "Company Name"

Switch ($sourceUser.State){
    "ACT" {$props.OfficePhone= "text";$ou = "text"}
    "NSW" {$props.OfficePhone= "text";$ou = "text"}
    "VIC" {$props.OfficePhone= "text";$ou = "text"}
    "QLD" {$props.OfficePhone= "text";$ou = "text"}
    "TAS" {$props.OfficePhone= "text";$ou = "text"}
    "SA" {$props.OfficePhone= "text";$ou = "text"}
    "WA" {$props.OfficePhone= "text";$ou = "text"}
}

Get-ADUser $targetUser | Set-ADUser $props -PassThru | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $ou -Server "text" -PassThru | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties $properties | ft -AutoSize -Property $properties

}
else {write-host "WARNING: NO NAME GIVEN `n" -foregroundcolor "red"}
```

This is partially tested and I would urge you to test this on non production users. Using the `$properties` you specify build a hashtable of all the associated values in the `$sourceUser`. Set the company statically and using a `switch` we set the value of the `.Phone` and what the `$ou` will be. When that is all done get the `$targetUser` and set the properties built using `@props`. `-PassThru` the user object to `Move-AdObject` to change the `$ou` and finally output the results with a final call to `Get-ADUser`. All the pipes could be split up but it should work. There could be other minor improvements but I am curious if you have similar issue with this code.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort on this one. Perhaps I'm not following your instructions properly. I get the error:

Set-ADUser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline 
input.
At line:29 char:26

Comment: I wonder what your `$props` looks like. I know there is some stuff that you cannot show here but i feel like one of those is your issue. If it was me I would try to set each of those properties manually. ie: `Set-Aduser $targetuser -StreetAddress "some address"` and then the next one. Also in the case where this failed does `Get-ADUser $targetUser` return anything?

Comment: Get-ADUser $targetUser returns the following fields

DistinguishedName : 
Enabled           : 
GivenName         : 
Name              : 
ObjectClass       : 
ObjectGUID        : 
SamAccountName    : 
SID               : 
Surname           : 
UserPrincipalName : 

$props returns correct values.